# Error when adding SharePoint Powershell snapin

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

When I run Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell I get

`Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 3.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (microsoft.sharepoint.powershell:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand`

I know this sounds dumb but I have searched Google for about 12 hours trying to just add this snapin. Im writting my first shell script and just need help getting off the start

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need the sharepoint install media to install the powershell pieces.

Comment: You can find all available snapins on a system using `Get-PSSnapin -Registered`

Comment: Did anyone find any solution to this please ? I still can't use Invoke-SQlcmd :(

Comment: Per Hunter's answer - you have to run the power shell on the actual server share-point is installed on.

Answer (score 2):

What is your SharePoint version, 2010 or 2013?
What is your Powershell version? (`$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`)

SharePoint 2010 expects PowerShell version 2, which you can get to by running `powershell -version 2`

[image]

NB.
(To the commenter above)
If you dont have SharePoint installed on the PC you get this message.

```
Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell' is not installed on this machine.
At line:1 char:13
+ Add-PSSnapin <<<<  Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand
```

Comment: I was running powershell version 3 with sharepoint 2010. can i install sharepoint somehow on a cliet?

Comment: SharePoint 2010 is only compatible with PowerShell v2, which you can access and use as in the screen shot above. To use SharePoint 2010 and the powershell commands together you need to have SharePoint installed on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I can understand you are using powershell version 3.0.
Please reboot your system and then try to add the snap-in.. It should work for you.

Comment: PS > Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell' is not installed on this computer.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand
PS> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      18362  752